# Override infowindow Zoom To function or fire second event using ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, infowindow

The Popup of ArcGIS JavaScript API has a 'Zoom To' link on it that zooms you 4 levels closer to the linked feature.

I'd like to fire another event after the default zoom to function executes.

Here is the link in the HTML.

```
<div class="actionsPane">
  <div class="actionList">
    <a class="action zoomTo" href="javascript:void(0);">Zoom to</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to add a function to the Zoom To click with jQuery like this:

```
$('.action.zoomTo').click(function() {alert('Clicked!');});
```

But the the function above occurs *before* the default function of 'Zoom To'.  I wouldn't mind their click function executing, so long as it fires *after* mine does.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disconnect the ESRI Zoom To function like this:

```
dojo.disconnect(map.infoWindow._eventConnections[4]);
```

This assume your var map = esri.Map(). The the fifth element in the _eventConnections array is the zoom to event.

Then you can attach your own events to the Zoom To with jQuery or dojo:

```
// Add custom zoom To
$('.action.zoomTo').click(function () { alert('First!'); });
$('.action.zoomTo').click(function () { alert('Second!'); });
```

It appears that the new connection can only be made after the an InfoTemplate is instantiated.